# Jasmine testing local array reduce

Tags: arrays, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am very new to Jasmine and struggle with its concepts. I would like to test if an array 'reduce' has been called.

```
export class QuestionController implements Controller {

    private questionnaireList: Questionnaire[];
    private questionList: Question[];
```

I build a select table that I want to test:

```
buildSelect(): void {
    let options = this.questionnaireList.reduce((result, qset) => result + this.templateForQuestionnaire(qset), '');
    let select = this.util.getElementById('quest-select');
    select.innerHTML = options;
}
```

I have tried things like:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(dummyQuestionnaireList, "reduce");
    spyOn(qc, "buildSelect").and.callThrough();
});

it('should call reduce on this.questionnaireList', () => {
        qc.buildSelect();
        expect(dummyQuestionnaireList.reduce).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should call util.getElementById', () => {
        qc.buildSelect();
        expect(u.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but I really have no idea what I am doing, in that I cannot even identify which tools are the right tools from Jasmine from its docs page.

Comment: This is a very odd way to test. You shouldn't care whether `reduce` is called but instead that the correct behaviour is exhibited - you should only check that `select.innerHTML` is set to what you'd expect. The same applied to checking that `util.getElementById` has been called